# Failed to submit credentials because of connector error

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to build my own connector for the first time. I'm getting the following error:

`Sorry, we failed to submit your credentials because there was an error in the connector in processing the credentials.`

Here is my code so far:

```
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.USER_TOKEN)
    .setHelpUrl('https://api-doc-help-url/authentication')
    .build();
}


function validateCredentials(userName, token) {
  var rawResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api/v2/stuff/' + userName , {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': userName + ':' + token
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  return rawResponse.getResponseCode() === 200;
}

function isAuthValid() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var userName = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.username');
  var token = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.token');

  return validateCredentials(userName, token);
}

function setCredentials(request) {
  var creds = request.userToken;
  var username = creds.username;
  var token = creds.token;

  var validCreds = checkForValidCreds(username, token);
  if (!validCreds) {
    return {
      errorCode: 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS'
    };
  }
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.username', username);
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.token', token);
  return {
    errorCode: 'NONE'
  };
}
```

I'm not sure how all this work exactly. I know that I need to pass the Authorization in the header with the following value `userName:token`

When deploying my manifest and clicking the Google Data Studio link I'm redirected to the select connector data studio interface. The error appear when I'm trying to submit Usernam and Token.

Comment: From your more recent questions, it seems like you were able to resolve the issue. Can you please let us know if that is the case?

Comment: Still got the same issue. I'm not able to pass the authflow.

Answer (score 0):

checkForValidCreds is not defined inside the function setCredentials. which is causing the error